# Waiting / hover time befor function starts

Tags: jquery, hover

I've got a function that works fine so far. But now i want, that the cursor needs to stay at least 2 sec. over the div "customers" to start the function or else the function doesnt start.

### Javascript

```
$('.customer').hover(function() {
                var tOutCustomer = null;
                var $this = $(this);

                    if ($this.hasClass("open")) {
                        tOutCustomer =  setTimeout(function () {
                            $this.find('.customer-icon').animate({left: "0"});
                            $this.find('.customer-description').animate({left: "100%"});
                        }, 1000);
                            $this.removeClass("open");


                    }  else {

                        $this.find('.customer-icon').animate({left: "-100%"});
                        $this.find('.customer-description').animate({left: "0"});
                        $this.addClass("open");
                        clearTimeout(tOutCustomer);
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeout function. Follow this link:

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html

Comment: But I think its better to do all this stuff with css if its ok in your project. You can set easier the timing.

Comment: Im sorry but I would like to do it just with jquery.